# Calcaulte the cosine similarity between two arrays and save the result in a matrix

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I have two arrays, A (size = (20, 200) and B (size = (15, 200)). I want to construct a matrix C (size = (20, 15)) s.t c[i,j] store the cosine similarity between elements A[i] and B[j].

I can do that using a loop, but it takes so long time if A and B are big arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized way with numpy would be:

```py
import numpy as np


A = np.random.uniform(size=(20, 200))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(15, 200))

normalized_A = A / np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
normalized_B = B / np.linalg.norm(B, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
cosine = (normalized_A[:, np.newaxis, :] * normalized_B[np.newaxis, :, :]).sum(axis=2)

# cosine.shape
# > (20, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scipy.spatial.distance.cosine function to compute the cosine similarity between two arrays:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine 
A = np.random.rand(20, 200) 
B = np.random.rand(15, 200) 
C = np.zeros((20, 15)) 
for i in range(20): 
    for j in range(15): 
        C[i, j] = cosine(A[i], B[j])
```

Comment: I am just asking if there is another solution without using for loop?